# exception while using excel workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am getting these exceptions in my code while i m writing some data in excel workbook using poi jars:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at WorkBookDemo.main(WorkBookDemo.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.UnsupportedFileFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

I added following jars:

1. xmlbeans-2.4.0
2. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11
3. poi-3.11
4. commons-logging-1.1
5. dom4j-1.6.1
6. log4j-1.2.17

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;

   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.Set;
   import java.util.TreeMap;

   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

   public class WorkBookDemo {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           //Blank workbook
           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

           //Create a blank sheet
           XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");

           //This data needs to be written (Object[])
           Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
           data.put("1", new Object[] {"ID", "NAME", "LASTNAME"});
           data.put("2", new Object[] {1, "Amit", "Shukla"});
           data.put("3", new Object[] {2, "Lokesh", "Gupta"});
           data.put("4", new Object[] {3, "John", "Adwards"});
           data.put("5", new Object[] {4, "Brian", "Schultz"});

          //Iterate over data and write to sheet
           Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
           int rownum = 0;
           for (String key : keyset)
           {
               Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
               Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
               int cellnum = 0;
               for (Object obj : objArr)
               {
                   Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                   if(obj instanceof String)
                       cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                   else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                       cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
               }
           }
           try
           {
           //Write the workbook in file system
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("exps.xlsx"));
               workbook.write(out);
               out.close();
               System.out.println("exps.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("exps.xlsx"));
```

[A file output stream is an output stream for writing data to a File or to a FileDescriptor. Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the underlying platform. Some platforms, in particular, allow a file to be opened for writing by only one FileOutputStream (or other file-writing object) at a time. In such situations the constructors in this class will fail if the file involved is already open.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Since you are explicitly creating a `File` object, and passing the same to `FileOutputStream` constructor. It assumes that the file `"exps.xlsx"` is already created. [[Reference.]](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/fileoutputstream.html)

Incase, it is not, you simply pass the name of the file in `FileOutputStream` constructor.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("exps.xlsx");
```

This will automatically create the file, incase it is already not created.

Moreover, I tested your given code and used the following `Maven` dependency and it worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Incase you are not using a `maven` project, you can explicitly add the aforementioned `jars` of the aforementioned versions.

Comment: The POI jars *must* always be from the same version - your advice here is dangerous as it mixes 3.9 and 3.10!

Comment: compability issues can happen.

Comment: Sry, my bad. mis-put the same in hurry!;

Comment: It was not working for me...the versions for all POI jars were different. I picked up similar versions for all 3 jars and now they are same.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing jar-files. I ran your code in my workspace and I added required jars to build path. It worked successively.

```
org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException is under poi-x.xx-xxx-xx.jar
```

No error in your code it is correct. Add jars to build path.

Answer (score 2):

the below list of jars required for apachePOI library should all be of same version like shown below  :

```
org.apache.poi.3.11
org.apache.poi-ooxml.3.11
org.apache.poi-ooxml-schemas.3.11
```

if the above jars of the same library are of different versions, then u will get the exception as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException"

Answer (score 0):

you can check for duplicate poi jars as well, suppose you need poi-ooxml-3.9. jar. but in your lib folder there is both poi-ooxml-3.11.jar, poi-ooxml-3.9.jar then remove poi-ooxml-3.11.jar, it should work then.

Comment: Why would you remove the newer jar? Surely you'd want to keep the newest one, with all the bug fixes in it, and remove the old one?