# can not convert xlsx to csv using poi api

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to convert xlsx file to csv file using below code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XLStoCSVConvert {

     static void xlsx(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
            // For storing data into CSV files
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                // Get the workbook object for XLSX file
                System.out.println("working......1");
                XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
                // Get first sheet from the workbook
                System.out.println("working......2");
                XSSFSheet sheet = wBook.getSheetAt(0);
                Row row;
                Cell cell;
                // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    row = rowIterator.next();

                    // For each row, iterate through each columns
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        cell = cellIterator.next();

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");

                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");

                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                                break;

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                data.append("" + ",");
                                break;
                            default:
                                data.append(cell + ",");

                        }
                    }
                }

                fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();

            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("/home/raptorjd4/Desktop/ToConsult.xlsx");
        //writing excel data to csv 
        File outputFile = new File("/home/raptorjd4/Desktop/RaptorTrackingSystem/ToConsult.csv");
        xlsx(inputFile, outputFile);

    }

}
```

But i am getting output,

Working......1
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException`

My jar in lib folder,

**poi-3.5-FINAL.jar**

**poi-ooxml-3.11.jar**

why i am getting this error when i mapped all needed jar file in lib folder.

Where am i doing mistake?

Comment: Please have a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398763/exception-while-using-excel-workbook

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace to your question, and mark the exact  line where the error occurs in your code?

Comment: @RealSkeptic check my updated question

Comment: Check the dependencies on your classpath, if still issue persist..give the sample dataset so that we can replicate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me your code worked just fine, below are the dependencies I added:-

[image]

The problem is either with the data in your excel or some missing dependency.
Ensure that you do have all the necessary dependencies on your classpath.

Comment: [Apache POI 3.7](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.7) is almost 5 years old, and there are a [huge number of bug fixes since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.7), why are you suggesting the OP to use such an old version?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part:

- poi-3.5-FINAL.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.11.jar

As explained in [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C):

> **Can I mix POI jars from different versions?**
>
> No. This is not supported.
>
> All POI jars in use must come from the same version. A combination such as poi-3.11.jar and poi-ooxml-3.9.jar is not supported, and will fail to work in unpredictable ways.

You *must* ensure that all of your Apache POI jars come from the same version!

Switch your jars to be from the same version, ideally the latest, and you should be good

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by adding below jar files,

```
poi-3.9.jar

poi-ooxml-3.9.jar

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar

xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

dom4j-1.6.1.jar
```

Comment: Those jars are, as the date in the name cunningly shows, almost 3 years old. Why have you gone for such an old version?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am new to poi so i ddint know about it. So where i can get latest all these working jar ?

Comment: @Gagravarr suggest me where i can get these all jar in single package ?

Comment: Go to the [Apache POI Website](http://poi.apache.org/) then click the [Download link](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) then download the latest binary distribution in either zip or tar (your preference), and you'll find all the jars and their dependencies in there. Magic!